# Start command only works when run manually

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm

I get the following error when installing PHP FPM:

```
Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini with new version
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
```

I tried the following tweaks in my dockerfile:

```
RUN echo exit 0 > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm start
RUN service php7.0-fpm start
```

None of this works, and PHP FPM isn't running on boot.

However if I ssh in and manually run the following command:

```
service php7.0-fpm start
```

Then it starts working! What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to provide the full path to the utility you invoked. When you do it from the ssh-session you have some `PATH` environment variable containing the list of directories looked for the given utility. And there is no such list in the docker.

Run manually:

```
which service
```

You'll get the full path to the utility. Provide that path to the config instead of single utility name.

Comment: I thought this was a shoe in to work, but it still didn't. I tried both: ```RUN usr/sbin/service php7.0-fpm start``` and ```RUN /usr/sbin/service php7.0-fpm start``` as part of the docker file and no luck, yet when I login and run it, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

> invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.

Try adding:

```
RUN printf "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

See: [How to solve “invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46247032/55075)

---

> invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel

Try:

```
RUN RUNLEVEL=1 dpkg --configure -a
```

or:

```
RUN RUNLEVEL=1 dpkg-reconfigure php7.0-fpm
```